# Android checkable context menu not remembering checked

Tags: android, contextmenu

I have a button which opens a context menu with a list of various options. Only one option can be selected at a time so I want to have a radio button next to each of them highlighting which item is currently selected. When I select an item from the context menu the radio button is selected and closes. Once I click the button to open the context menu the previously selected item is not selected.

How do I get the context menu to remember which item was previously selected?

Secondly, when the activity is first created a default option is selected. How do I set an initial default which can then be overwritten when another context menu item is selected? I can set `android:checked="true"` in the XML but can this be overwritten when a different item is selected?

Java:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.browse);
    Button buttonView = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button_view);
    buttonView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            registerForContextMenu(v);
            openContextMenu(v);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.setHeaderTitle(R.string.menu_title);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case(R.id.item1):
            if(item.isChecked()) {
                item.setChecked(false);
            } else {
                item.setChecked(true);
            }
            break;
        case(R.id.item2):
            if(item.isChecked()) {
                item.setChecked(false);
            } else {
                item.setChecked(true);
            }
            break;
        case(R.id.item3):
            if(item.isChecked()) {
                item.setChecked(false);
            } else {
                item.setChecked(true);
            }
            break;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
    return true;
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:id="@+id/context_menu" android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:id="@+id/item1"
            android:title="@string/context_menu_item1" />
        <item android:id="@+id/item2"
            android:title="@string/context_menu_item2" />
        <item android:id="@+id/item3"
            android:title="@string/context_menu_item3" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is that your items don't save the state between displaying of menu.
So each time you call setChecked, it works only for the currently shown menu and resets for the next.

You should save the checked state in an external structure like a boolean array for example.

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.setHeaderTitle(R.string.menu_title);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);

    // loop for menu items
    for (int i = 0; i < menu.size(); ++i) {
        MenuItem mi = menu.getItem(i);
        // check the Id as you wish
        if (mi.getItemId() == R.id.item2) {
            mi.setChecked(true); 
        }
    }
}
```

In order to search a menu item, you can also use the findItem function:

```
MenuItem mi = menu.findItem(R.id.item2)
```

Comment: So I store the user input when selected. How do I then use this to show the item as selected the next time the context menu is opened?

Comment: I've updated the answer. So you should use onCreateContextMenu and set checked state here.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you have to save your user input somewhere and set the checked states explicitly after inflating the layout.

By the way, you could write your item selected switch like so:

```
switch (item.getItemID()) {
case R.id.item1:
case R.id.item2:
case R.id.item3:
   item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());
}
```

Comment: Each case contains more than just this but I just used this as an example. +1 for your simplified setChecked() though!

How do I get the user input?

Comment: item.isChecked() is your user input. Btw, i think StackOverflow would ask you to start a new question if this doesn't answer enough...

Comment: @Bondax item.isChecked() is just checking if the item was already checked... it's not the user input.